# Is it required to use async functions in koa framework?

Tags: node.js, async-await, koa, koa2

I started learn koa.js and on koa documentation I found such demo code:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(async ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This middleware use async function, but code is sync. Is this required to use async function everywhere in koa or there is specific case for it?

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer :

You can use sync function as well, it will work perfectly.

### Long answer :

#### Promise vs async

Async function can be replaced by synchronous functions returning **Promise** into a **sync** function (see http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html for more info)

#### Koa compose

Koa is using koa-compose to handle middlewares.

If you check compose function in
https://github.com/koajs/compose/blob/master/index.js

Code is

```
 return Promise.resolve(fn(context, function next () {
  return dispatch(i + 1);
 }))
```

Your middleware function `fn` is then bound into `Promise.resolve` which means that the output will be considered as a Promise even if you return non-Promise.

#### Sync Promise

It's not documented anywhere and would suggest you to avoid using undocumented patterns and I would do :

```
 app.use(function(context){
   // ...
   return Promise.resolve();
 })
```

As a sync design compatible with **async**.